# Does the "Disease Zones Expand" emergency event only apply to cities with cubes of more than one color?

Tags: pandemic, pandemic-state-of-emergency

The *Disease Zones Expand* emergency event card states to

> Add 1 cube of every non-matching color to each city with different colored cube(s).

Does this mean to add cubes to cities which have cubes of non-native colors (e.g. LA has a blue cube but no yellow cube, so it gets a second blue cube, and Mexico City has a blue and a yellow, so it only gets a second blue), or add cubes to cities which have cubes of 2 or more colors (e.g. LA has a blue cube but no yellow, so it gets no new cubes, whereas Mexico City has both a blue and a yellow, so it gets one extra of each)? Or is it something in between?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [this thread on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/18547069#18547069), game designer Tom Lehmann addresses this concern. User joekeck posted this as a reword:

> "if any cities contain any cube(s) (other than purple) that do not match that city's color, then add an additional cube of that cube color"

and Tom responded:

> In spirit, yes. The problems with this wording (which is similar to the wording I originally submitted to Z-Man) are: A) "that cube color" could conceivably be read as a cube of the city's color ("that" isn't unambiguous here) and B) it's too long for the card text area.

So in your example, both Los Angeles and Mexico city receive an additional blue cube, but no yellow cubes are added.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, you need to add a cube to the non-native cubes

- so LA (which is yellow) but has a blue cube RECEIVES an extra blue cube
- Mexico (which is yellow) and has both a blue and yellow cube RECEIVES an extra blue cube (not a yellow one, because that IS matching)

Comment: You were first, but @SocioMatt 's answer included clarification from the game designer, so I marked it as the answer instead.

Comment: Not a user of BGG, so... :) thanks for the feedback!